# Count Cell Values based on Time Range

Tags: excel

I want to get the total "Contact" made between the times on column G and H using the Start(Col D2) and End(Col E12). How to accomplish this?

[image: Count cell values based on time]

Comment: Is the count based on call start time or end time or both. If a call starts at 8:50 am and ends at 10:10 am, does it get counted once or thrice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `sumifs` to do this

```
=SUMIFS($B:$B,$D:$D,">="&G1,$E:$E,"<="&H1)
```

Edit:  Use the following

First sumifs checks to see if a contact has started in the specified range, the second sumifs checks to see if a contact has ended in the specified range

```
=SUMIFS($B:$B,$D:$D,">="&G1,$D:$D,"<="&H1)+SUMIFS($B:$B,$E:$E,">="&G1,$E:$E,"<="&H1)
```

Comment: Realized the way this is setup you will have contacts "disappear" because your ranges are set for hour intervals and you can have a contact last longer than an hour.  If you give me more information on how you want to handle this I can edit the answer.

Comment: ty for that, but it doesn't seem to add up. i need it to count the total contact made during the time. EG. 10am-11am, it is more than 10?

Comment: Basically i just want to get the total "Contact" count between times, maybe there's a better way?

Comment: So taking the first contact as an example.  Would it only show up once in the 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM range? or will it show up twice in the 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM range as well as the 11:00 AM to 12:00 PM?

Comment: the contact count will add as long as the Start and End time is in the time range. yep, twice or maybe more. tnx for your help! can't get my mind around it.

Comment: @TheDon  I have updated my answer, please use the second formula.  Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: you nailed it! tyvm!